# SVM - Works/Doesn't work for big range of numbers?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, svm

I have been playing around with the SVM and I have stumbled upon something interesting.

It might be something I may be doing wrong, hence the post for comments and clarification.

I have data set of around 3000 x 30.

Each value is in the range of -100 to 100. Plus, they are not integers. They are floating point numbers. They are not evenly distributed.

It's like, 
the numbers are -99.659, -99.758, -98.234 and then we wont have something till like -1.234, -1.345 and so.

So even though the range is big, the data is clustered around at some points and they usually differ by fraction values.
( I thought and from what my readings and understanding goes, this shouldn't ideally affect the SVM classification accuracy. Correct me if I am wrong please. **Do Comment on this with a yes or no of I am right or wrong.** )

My labels for the classification are 0 and 1.

So, then I take a test data of 30 x 30 and tried to test my SVM.

I am getting an accuracy of somewhere around 50% when is the kernel_function as mlp.

In other methods, I simply get 0's and NaN's as result which is weird as no 1s were in the output and I didn't understand the NaN's in the output labels.

So, mlp was basically giving me the best results and that too just 50%.

I have then used the method as 'QP' with 'mlp' as kernel_function and the code has been running for like 8 hours now. I don't suppose, something as small as 3400 x 30 should take that much time.

So the question really is, is the SVM a wrong choice for the data I have? (As asked above). 
Or is there something I am missing out that is causing the accuracy to drop significantly?

Also, I know the input data is not screwed up, because I tested the same using a Neural Network and I was able to have a very good accuracy.

Is there a way to make SVM work? Because, from what I have read on the internet- SVM should generally work better than Neural Network in this label deciding problem.

Comment: I'd recommend trying [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) and seeing what happens; the matlab interface is similar but the library is maybe more mature.

Comment: ^Okay. I'll try that and let you know what happens.

Comment: I did try the libsvm. However, there has been no significant improvement in the results. the accuracy came to be around 55% which is pretty bad.

Comment: Okay, I'd try scaling your features e.g. to have std dev 1 and seeing if that helps - that can be pretty important.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be having some numerical stability problems that are being caused by the small size of the data clusters (although I'm not sure why that would be: it really shouldn't). SVM shouldn't care as an *algorithm* about the distributions you are describing: in fact, it should do a pretty good job under normal circumstances when presented something so distinctly separated.

One thing to investigate is if any of your columns are very strongly correlated. Really strongly correlated column groups should be replaced by a single column for performance reasons *and* I have seen implementations that become numerically unstable when faced with almost perfect correlation in columns.

Comment: Can you give a small example of what do you mean by strongly co-related?

Comment: If you have multiple columns that are effectively representing the same data. For example, I have encountered databases where the weight and volume were both recorded, but the measurements were all of the same substance. This means we can derive the weight from the volume.

This is not a good use of processor time (performance reasons) and it can cause some algorithms to generate infinitesimals, in turn creating underflow conditions.

Comment: Oh Okay. I will check that, but I doubt there are such columns.

Comment: An alternative explanation is that the SVM you are using simply has inherent stability issues. If your data is a clearly clustered as you describe a SVM should have no trouble partitioning the hyperplanes. Tightly clustered data is easier, not harder, to separate.

Comment: ^Exactly the reason why I am baffled. If anything, this should have given a very high accuracy! And what do you mean by the SVM I use has inherent stability issues? I am using the in built MATLAB SVM. How do I check for this stability issue? I mean, is there some sort of a test that I can conduct that would hint me towards it?

Comment: Many AI algorithms have to be carefully implemented to avoid numerical stability problems. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability I can't imagine MATLAB's SVM would be poorly implmented.

Comment: And I did check, there are no such columns that might be co-related.

Comment: Oh okay.  Yes, that is not a problem with MATLABs SVM. Any more ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14715/discussion-between-godeke-and-sylar)

Answer (score 0):

While independent features are nice, it is not neccesary for the algorithm, after all, we are saying in advance we do not know what features contribute *what* to the data.  Are you scaling your data?  Also, 30 data points is perhaps a little small to create a training set.  Can we see your code?

Comment: Its 3000x30. So essentially 3000 rows of training with 30 features. No, I am not scaling data. I wasn't really sure if that actually helps with the SVM or not. And there are like 2 commands in MATLAB - x=svmtrain(myTrainingSet,myLabels,'kernel_function','mlp') and the svmclassify command. I didn't implement it. I used the in built MATLAB one- so essentially no code as such.